# Is Flash embedding considered as Active X?

Tags: javascript, flash, activex, embedding

not sure if this has been answered yet, but I thought to give it a shot.

I want to find out, what causes Active X controls and whether Flash embedding would be considered as one? I'm embedding flash using swfobject.

I'm not doing any of Windows Media Player embedding or XHR in my application.

That would be really helpful.

Thanks.

K.

Comment: What are you asking exactly? Only IE makes use of ActiveX and Flash when running in that browser is implemented as an ActiveX control; on other browsers/OSs its implemented as a plug-in.

Comment: I think this is what I was asking, whether IE treats Flash embed as ActiveX.

Answer (score 1):

Flash Player running within Internet Explorer is an ActiveX control.